# Define different screen resolution when external monitor is plugged in on MBP retina w/ OSX 10.9

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have a MBP retina with OSX 10.9 on it and I'm trying to automatically change my laptop screen resolution when an external monitor is attached or detached. [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7628/define-different-screen-resolution-when-external-monitor-is-plugged-in) is the same but for a different version of OSX and doesn't work with my version.

For example, when I attach an external monitor, I want the laptop screen to display at a lower resolution, then when the external screen is removed I want the laptop screen to display at the highest resolution again.

Is there an easy way to do with, or can someone give me step by step instructions?

Comment: What model MBP do you have? Retina or non?

Comment: Retina - have changed question to reflect. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/) that, I believe, will allow you to predefine resolutions based on which display you are using. It costs about $20 but it's shareware, so you can try before you buy.

Answer (score 0):

Go into system preferences, then displays. On the external monitor, while holding the option key, click the scaled button. A list of resolutions should appear.